# Help with Javascript in JSP page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a JSP which gets a value called sum from the DB...

```
String sum= request.getAttribute("s").toString();
int s = Integer.parseInt(sum);
```

I have a field in a form called weight who's value cannot exceed sum.

So on clicking submit i'm running a function called validate. Which would check if field is greater than or equal to sum but it keeps giving me the warning all the time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
    var x= document.getElementById("s");
    if(document.getElementById("weight").value>x)
    {
        alert("Weight exceeds maximum limit...!!!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}   
</script>
```

Would appreciate the help..

Comment: Just curious if you're doing things the right way: does validation also work if you turn off JavaScript in your browser? (i.e. you're also doing exactly the same validation in the server side). If not, you've got something to think about :)

Comment: Yes i'm doing the validation on the server side aswell.... Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with JSP. You need to parse the values into numbers using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) before comparing. This is because the `.value` attribute is always a string. You are also comparing an element's value with an element, which does not make sense.

Try this:

```
function validate()
{
    var weight = parseFloat(document.getElementById("weight").value),
        maxWeight = parseInt(document.getElementById("s").value, 10);
    if(weight > maxWeight)
    {
        alert("Weight exceeds maximum limit...!!!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: it still excepts value's greater than weight

Comment: Is there an HTML element in the page with ID `s`? What is its `value`?

Comment: <input name="weight" id="weight" type="text"/>

Comment: I didn't ask about an element with ID `weight`, I asked about an element with ID `s`.

Comment: You need to make it accessible to JavaScript, then, as in @medopal's answer. Java runs on the server, JavaScript runs in the browser. There's no magic to make the two "see" each other.

Comment: I did this <input type="hidden" name="s" id="s" value="<%=sum%>"/>

and i worked

Comment: You can also dump the variable directly into JavaScript which will avoid unnecessary DOM elements, and simplify the JS code.

Answer (score 1):

`s` is a Java variable so you cannot reference it through `document`.

Try something like:

```
var x = <%=Integer.parseInt(sum); %>
if (document.getElem...
```